# User with custom role cannot access custom menu item in Magento 2 admin interface

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, permissions, acl, admin-user

I want to give permission to admin user for a custom module,
before creating a acl.xml the module name was not coming in list, after acl.xml its coming but admin user is not able to see in his menu.

Here is acl.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Catalog::catalog" title="Products" sortOrder="30">
                    <resource id="Magento_Catalog::catalog_inventory" title="Inventory" sortOrder="10">
                        <resource id="Sup_Brand::shopbybrand" title="ShopByBrand" sortOrder="10" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Here's the menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 PinkBlue. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="sup_brand::shopbybrand" title="ShopByBrand" module="Sup_Brand" sortOrder="21" parent="Magento_Catalog::inventory" resource="Sup_Brand::sample" action="sup_brand/items/"/>

    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Please also post the XML for your menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change in your acl.xml with this line

```
<resource id="Sup_Brand::sample" title="ShopByBrand" sortOrder="10" />
```

and also in your adminhtml controller, in your case it must be PATH_TO_YOUR_ADMIN_CONTROLLER/Items/Index 
add this function

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
  return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Sup_Brand::sample');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your menu resource should match your acl resource.

So in your case you need to replace:

```
<resource id="Sup_Brand::shopbybrand" title="ShopByBrand" sortOrder="10" />
```

With:

```
<resource id="Sup_Brand::sample" title="ShopByBrand" sortOrder="10" />
```

in your `acl.xml`

Comment: For privacy i have edited the name of module now updated plz check

Comment: @supriyamishra see my updated answer